# Insert new cell in Jupyter Notebook from javascript widget

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a widget that can generate code. Once the code is created I would like to have a button that, when clicked on, will insert the code into a new cell. I have found a function called [create_code_cell](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4983) but don't know how to get it to work from javascript or how to embed it in a python class that can be called.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from traitlets import CInt
from traitlets import Unicode
import base64
from IPython.display import Javascript, display
from IPython.utils.py3compat import str_to_bytes, bytes_to_str

    class CodeBuilerWidget(widgets.DOMWidget):
        _view_name = Unicode('CodeBuilerView').tag(sync=True)
        value = CInt().tag(sync=True)

        def create_code_cell(code='', where='below'):
            """Create a code cell in the IPython Notebook.

            Parameters
            code: unicode
            Code to fill the new code cell with.
            where: unicode
            Where to add the new code cell.
            Possible values include:
                at_bottom
                above
                below"""
            encoded_code =                 bytes_to_str(base64.b64encode(str_to_bytes(code)))
            display(Javascript("""
                var code = IPython.notebook.insert_cell_{0}('code');
                code.set_text(atob("{1}"));
            """.format(where, encoded_code)))

    %%javascript
    require(["jupyter-js-widgets"], function(widgets) {

        var CodeBuilerView = widgets.DOMWidgetView.extend({
        render: function() { 

            var that = this;

            this.$btn = $('<button id="btn">Insert Code</button>');
            this.$el.append(this.$btn);
            this.$btn.click(function() {
              alert( "Handler for .click() called. Want to run create_code_cell() python method" );
            });

        },

    });

    widgets.ManagerBase.register_widget_view('CodeBuilerView', CodeBuilerView);
    });
```

Many Thanks